# How to connect to PostgreSQL databases from php?

Tags: php, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying to connect to a pgadmin database.
I've replaced NAME, IPADDRESS, USERNAME and PASSWORD below.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=NAME;host=IPADDRESS';
        $user = 'USERNAME';
        $password = 'PASSWORD';

        try {
            $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

But it times out

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation
> timed out in

What could this mean? Is this the right way to connect to postgreSQL databases from php?

Comment: First: mysql != postgres. Use the correct driver.

Comment: Check the PHP manual for the dsn: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php

Comment: Thanks, changing the driver sql to pgsql worked for me: $oPdo = new \PDO("pgsql:host={$sDbHost};port=5432;dbname={$dbname}", $user, $pass);

Comment: Above, change the first row of code to: $dsn = 'pgsql:dbname=NAME;host=IPADDRESS';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to add `pgsql:`  in connection string like below example

`$dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host=IPADDRESS;dbname=NAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');`

You can also get the reference from the below URL

https://www.a2hosting.in/kb/developer-corner/postgresql/connect-to-postgresql-using-php